# How to change the starting page number in word in microsoft interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

With the code provided below, when I press a button, The pages are numbered. However if I have selected any page other than the first page that page number becomes the starting page number i.e. Clicking the button while selecting page 2 sets the number on page 1 to "2". How can I make it start at page one in any circumstance.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc = //Gets current Document
oject CurrentPage = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages;
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
//Gets the Header
Doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekPrimaryHeader;
//Adds the page number
Doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(
Doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, ref CurrentPage, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object HeaderFooter contains a PageNumbers property that has several interesting properties, including StartingNumber.

see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194253.aspx) for some information on how to retrieve the correct HeaderFooter instance.

Comment: This is what i have fiqured out in C#. I'm just not sure what "i" and "j" shoul d be. `Doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Sections[i].Headers[j].PageNumbers.StartingNumber = 1;`

Comment: my guess would be ActiveDocument.Sections[1].Footers[wdHeaderFooterPrimary].PageNumber‌​s.StartingNumber = 1;

If your document has several sections, I'd say loop on the sections set starting number accordingly. You may have to do something special for first pages of sections depending on your document : (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194465.aspx)

Have you tried playing with the numbers ?

Comment: I'm running through all the numbers with a for loop but nothing is happening other than "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"